# pass variable from view to activity

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity

I have been studying some code trying to learn more, the basic code is very simple. There is a xml layout file, and activity file and view file.
Eg.
simpleprog_layout.xml, SimpleProgView.java and SimpleProgActivity.java

I was looking at how a number of things are done and was trying to work out how a value could be passed from the view file for use in the activity file. 
Can some one point me in the right direction?

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 0):

Value being passed from View to Activity . 
If it's to do with attaining reference of the View . It can be done using 2 Approaches

1. FindviewById()
2. ViewBinding

And if you'd wish to share a View's value to Another Activity , or to another view of Any other activity it can be achieved majorly in two ways .

1. Intents
2. Global Variables

Let's say for example there exists a String "name" and you wish to pass it to the ProfilePage of your application

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("user_name", username); // where Tag is user_name and the variable that holds value is username
startActivity(intent);
```

and the activity is able to receive the value using :

```
String userNameFromAnotherActivity= getIntent().getStringExtra("user_name"); // same Tag should be used
```

And with respect to global variable , any Activity is able to access the value with held in that variable.